# read a text file and remove all occurences of a duplicates

Tags: java

I have a text file called test1.txt I want to remove all occurences of the duplicates. that means only unique words will be there. 
example.

test1.txt:

```
hello i am a businessman  i am also a student
```

output should be:

```
hello businessman also student
```

my approach was like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test1.txt"));

        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            list1.add(input.next());

        }


        for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<list1.size();j++){
            if(list1.get(i).equals(list1.get(j))){
                list1.remove(j);
                j--;
               }
             }
         }

        System.out.println("List 1: " + list1);


    }

}
```

but it's not what i am looking for. i want to remove all occurence of duplicate so that i can output only unique words.

Comment: Read each line from a file, extract each word, put in a HashSet and then write to file.

Comment: Instead of ArrayList you can use a Set implementation which will add only unique values to it. And you can then just iterate and write it to file.

Comment: Try inserting everything inside a HashSet instead of an ArrayList. If the insert fails (because it is already present), then add it to a second HashSet. This is so that you know you have already encountered the word. The second set will contain all the words that need to be deleted from the first set to get the true solo occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an implementation of Set interface. Java provides multiple of them:

- [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): This implementation does not maintain any order
- [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): This implementation maintains natural order (Lexicographical comparison for Strings, Increasing order for numbers, etc)
- [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html): This implementation maintains the order of insertion.

Like others mentioned, this looks like a clear homework problem. So I am not going to code the solution for you. However, I will show you a sample algorithm that can work.

Step 1: Open the file to read words one by one.
Step 2: Declare two sets, one for storing all the words and one for storing the duplicates.
Step 3: Read the words one by one and try inserting into the first set. Java's add method for set returns a boolean stating true or false based on insertion succeeding or failing.
Step 4: Try to insert in first set.
Step 4.1: If insertion passed, this means that the word has never been encountered so far. Move on to the next word and do Step 4 again.
Step 4.2: If insertion fails, that means that the word has already been seen in before and hence we should not have it in the final list. So put in the second list. Move on the next word and do Step 4 again.
Step 5: After finishing all the words, you will have a set of unique words in the first set (Set A) and a set of words that occurred more than once in that paragraph. (Set B). 
Step 6: Perform A - B (Set of all words in A but not in B)
Step 7: The result above has all the words that occurred only once.

Note that this is just one kind of algorithm for the solution. There are other solutions using other data structures. (You can use HasMap, where you can map each word to the number of times it occurred and then print all those out that occured only once). Also note that you can implement the solution above using ArrayLists as well. Figure out how these work and you will really learn something.

Comment: `HashSet.add(obj)` will insert `obj`, only if it is **not already present** in the set

Comment: Please mark an anwer as accepted if it really helped you in solving your problem. @sajibzzz

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap to track each word and its occurrence in the given text file.

> **Key** -> word,  **value** -> word count

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test1.txt"));

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        list1.add(input.next());
    }

    for (String word : list1) {
        if (wordMap.get(word) == null) {
            wordMap.put(word, 1);
        } else {
            wordMap.put(word, wordMap.get(word) + 1);
        }
    }

    //If output order does not important just loop through wordMap
    for (String word : list1) {
        if(wordMap.get(word) == 1) {
            System.out.print(word + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> hello businessman also student

Answer (score 0):

Tackle the sentence word-by-word. If the word has not been seen before, add it to a "dictionary" of words that have been seen. If the word is in the dictionary, remove it.

First split the string into an array of words, then loop through that array following the above logic.

Comment: This is clearly a homework assignment or you are learning how to code. I will not provide you code as this is counter-intuitive to learning.

Comment: I don't want the full code.. Just want to know how to implement these part you are saying. Tackle the sentence word-by-word. If the word has not been seen before, add it to a "dictionary" of words that have been seen

Comment: You want help implementing "the part I am saying" also known as the answer? You know that this is such a common homework problem you will have no problem cheating with Google.

Answer (score 0):

I am only writing this, because there are a lot of answers that give complex and non-optimal solutions.

The advice that @Sambit gave is simple and you should do just that!

From the code you already have, just use `list1`.

```
public class MyClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test1.txt"));

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        list1.add(input.next());

    }

    // This will automatically remove all duplicates from your list.
    HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>(list1);

    // Print all the unique words
    for(String word : uniqueWords)
      System.out.println(word);
}
```

**Output:**

> hello i am a businessman also student

A set is a collection of distinct objects, which means that there are no duplicates.

The documentation for a `HashSet` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: This is not the right way to go. This solution removes only duplicate entries. Not duplicates themselves. For Ex:
Input: hello i am a businessman  i am also a student
Expected OutPut: hello businessman also student
Your Output (as stated): hello i am a businessman also student

Your solution removed the duplicate entry of I, am and a. What the OP needed was a way to remove all occurrences of any word if there was a duplicate in the sentence

Comment: @ArunSubramanian Oh, I see, thanks for telling me. What I would do in this case, would be to create a subclass of `HashSet`, let's call it `UniqueSet` and then override the constructor to remove all occurences of an object that appears multiple times, instead of keeping the first instance. This way the OP can reuse this class if or when they need to. I will edit when I get the chance, currently drowning in work

Comment: Yes, You could do something like that or just use 2 HashSet. Create 2 HashSet called seenOnce and moreThanOnce. For every word, see if it is present in moreThanOnce. If not, then check in seenOnce. If it is not here either, then you are encountering this for the first time. Add it to seenOnce. If it is already there in seenOnce, then this is the 2nd time you are coming across the same word. So remove it from seenOnce and put it in moreThanOnce. If it is already present in moreThanOnce, then you can just skip ahead to the next word. In the end, return seenOnce as your result.